# How do I replay current chapter from beginning?

Tags: xbox-360, syndicate-2012

So there was an unfortunate checkpoint placement in the chapter about chasing down Lilly (after seeing her through the glass disembarking from the dropship) where a you jump onto a big rotating metal platform and I missed the jump.
The game saved mid-jump and reloading results in me dying continuously.

I can replay previous chapters from the main menu but I have found no way to replay the current chapter from the beginning.

Is there a way to get back to a previous checkpoint or to the beginning of the chapter so I don't have to restart the whole game again, from the beginning?

Comment: This is the 2012 version of the game, yes?

Comment: Yes, it is, XBox 360 version.